# Interesting question on C# pattern matching to cast a type

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

I understand that I can use pattern matching to cast a type.

For example:

```
decimal? ticketId;

if (ticketId is { } nonNullableTicketId) {....}
```

Here, casting `ticketId` to `decimal` works

However:

```
string? ticket2;

if (ticket2?.Trim() is { } rawPlantNumber) {....}
```

Cast `ticket2` to `string` does not work. `ticket2` is still `string?`

Why is this?

Correction (Note: I'm using #nullable enable in the code)

Comment: First of all actually there is no casting happening. Second of all - what behaviour have you expected, what should have worked and is not working?

Comment: I believe there is. Mabey I've stated it wrongly. I'm using #nullable enable in the code and I forgot to say that (I'll correct that). In the first example, ticketId (nullable decimal) is cast to (non-nullable) in the variable nonNullableTicketId. In the second exable that isn't happening with the string.

Comment: How do you check the second case? Also which version of compiler/ framework are you using? cause for me there is no warnings about nullability of neither `rawPlantNumber` nor `ticket2` inside `if`.

Comment: Check out [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F6OlHA)

Comment: C#9. I'm using VS Enterprise. VS Resharper shows nonNullableTicketId as decimal not decimal? VS Resharper shows rawPlantNumber as string?  I'll try to get the IL to check it.

Comment: Also I would say that you should add your last comment to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the reason for such behaviour is that in second case you are using [property pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/#property-patterns) without explicitly specifing the type for **reference** type variable (`rawPlantNumber`), so compiler needs to infer it's type, and it seems to use the same rules as mentioned in [C# 8 specification proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/nullable-reference-types-specification#nullable-implicitly-typed-local-variables) for implicitly typed local variables (with `var`):

> `var` infers an annotated type for **reference** types, and type parameters that aren't constrained to be a value type. For instance:
>
> - in `var s = "";` the `var` is inferred as `string?`.
> - in `var t = new T();` with an unconstrained `T` the `var` is inferred as `T?`.

If you specify type explicitly as `string` you will get expected type for `rawPlantNumber`:

```cs
if (ticket2?.Trim() is string { } rawPlantNumber){}
```

Comment: Ah, good catch. And also I didn't know you could use a type specification after the is operator when also using the not-null pattern { }. And,     if (ticket2?.Trim() as string is { } rawPlantNumber){} definitely won't work.

Comment: Note to self: I'll need to  report to Resharper that " is string { } " flags as a warning saying "The source expression is always of pattern's type, matches on all non-null values." This required me to add // ReSharper disable once PatternAlwaysOfType, to clear the warning.

Comment: @K.CarterSr. Also for me Rider marks `rawPlantNumber` as `string`, not as `string?`.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used pattern matching much yet, but I see two things going on here.

First is the the value type vs reference type situation. The `ticket2` value reasonably could still be null, while the `ticketId` value *cannot* be null... there is always some default value for primitive types like decimal. But I don't  think that's what happened here.

The second is the non-null check (`is {}`) did not look directly at the `ticket2` value, but rather then result of the `Trim()` call. Perhaps this tricks the compiler such that it's not sure `ticket2` is safe to use directly as a string.